# Redirect Standard Output with Shell Execute

Tags: c#, redirect, io, command-prompt

I understand how to redirect `StandardIO` streams from `Process` objects in `C#` in general. However, I have to use `ShellExecute` for a particular command to work.

Consequently, I am unable to redirect these streams which I need for logging purposes.

I've tried redirecting it like this:

```
procStart.FileName = m1g;
procStart.Arguments = ">> output.txt";
```

At which point I plan on just reading the text file back, but this doesn't seem to work.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe commands are implemented by `cmd.exe`. So you need to run `cmd /c` and add your executable path as argument

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c " + yourexecutablecommandline + " >> output.txt" );
```